# Angular 2 rc1 router parameters and parentheses

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm developing a small app using Angular 2 rc and have an issue with the new router.

My router parameters include parentheses '(' ')'. Everything works fine with router.navigate(), but when accessing the link directly (e.g. hitting http://aweso.me/place;s=(r) in browser) Angular 2 generates an error:

*Uncaught (in promise): Cannot match any routes. Current segment: 'aux:r'. Available routes:*

Did anybody come up with the same issue?

**UPDATE**
It seems to be a bug in Router that yet to be fixed https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/4895